# Properly using Regex in Java, Regex not matching

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check if a string contains exactly 1 alphabetic char, that may or may not be preceded by any of ~, ! or ?. The expression I have set to match against is:

```
if (this.str.matches("[!~?]{1,9}?[a-z]{1}")) {
```

but when the input I have (this.str) is equal to 'p', this if block is not triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Some strings that should match:

```
!!~?p
p
~p
???!!?!??!~p
```

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: If the punctuation symbol (`!`, `~` and `?`) can be optional (can be absent), use `"[!~?]{0,9}[a-z]"`. Or even ``"[!~?]*[a-z]"`` where `*` means *0 or more occurrences*.

Comment: Would `~!???~~!!x` be valid? If the "alphabetic char" can only preceded by 1 character, use `"[!~?]?\\p{L}"`, where `\\p{L}` means any Unicode letter, not just a-z.

Comment: Please update your question with a set of strings that should and should not match for the desired outcome

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `[!~?]{0,9}?[a-z]`. The issue was the `{1,9}` matches ~, !, or ? ONE to nine times. You state that its optional and therefore should be ZERO to nine times.

Try your regex out at https://regex101.com/r/m1ad8X/1.

Try @WiktorStribiżew correction at https://regex101.com/r/m1ad8X/2

And my solution at https://regex101.com/r/m1ad8X/3